# Cloud Foundry and Let's Encrypt

Tags: node.js, ssl, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, lets-encrypt

I'm new to Cloud Foundry, as I've always run my own Debian servers and installed Node.JS on top of that.

I've managed to create a Node.JS app that runs on Cloud Foundry, but would like to have Let's Encrypt certificates generated and renewed automatically in a `/ssl` folder in my app. It's not for running HTTPS but for more complex operations such as signing files.

Is there a way to have Let's Encrypt run and generate, and renew, certificates in a Cloud Foundry enviroment?

Normally I would just install the Certbot ACME client and run a cronjob for this task. But that is not possible in Cloud Foundry, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it myself but did you look at https://github.com/bsyk/cf-letsencrypt ?